# ElasticSearch geo_distance filter is not returning any hits

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using ElasticSearch (1.4.0) to perform my searching.

I have managed to set up ElasticSearch and everything works great except the geo_location filter.

Whenever I use the geo_location filter, no results are returned.
Note that ElasticSearch does not return any errors. Simply there are no hits returned even though I made sure that there are nearby entities to my search point.

This is a simplified version of my PHP params array which I am using to test geo_distance filter:

```
    $searchParams['index'] = 'myname';
    $searchParams['type']  = 'myentity';

    $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['geo_distance'] = 
                    [
                        'distance' => '50km',
                        'address.geopoint' => $lat . "," $lng
                    ];
```

And this is the curl request body which does not return any hits too:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "50km",
                    "address.geopoint" : "51.43,-2.54"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my mapping:

```
{  
   "myname":{  
      "mappings":{  
         "myentity":{  
            "properties":{  
               "address":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "country":{  
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "geopoint":{  
                        "type":"geo_point",
                        "lat_lon":true
                     },
                     "house":{  
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "postcode":{  
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "street":{  
                        "type":"string"
                     },
                     "town":{  
                        "type":"string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "categories":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "tags":{  
                  "type":"string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the document I expect to get as a hit:

```
[_source] => Array (
    [categories] => Array (
    )
    [tags] => Array (
    )
    [address] => Array (
        [street] => Bristol Road
        [geopoint] => 51.4307381,-2.5417914
        [town] => Bristol
        [house] => 1
        [postcode] => BS4 5NL
        [country] => UK
    )
)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest trying this out of your php client. Just using `curl` or `marvel`. If the problem still persists, update the post with your query, your data that you believe it should be returned, the mapping and ES version.

Comment: I have tried to use curl, but its still the same. Both PHP client and curl gives same results. I have updated my question with more data. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html#_lat_lon_as_array_4):

> Format in [lon, lat], note, the order of lon/lat here in order to conform with GeoJSON.

So I think you should try:

`address.coordinates = [$lng, $lat]`

---

EDIT: Answer after your edition

Since you posted your mapping I see your real problem now. As you are using a [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) for `address` object you need a [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) similar to:

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "address",
            "query": {
                "filtered": {
                    "filter": {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "50km",
                            "geopoint": "51.43,-2.54"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's either that or stop using a nested type (If I'm not wrong it's just removing `"type":"nested",` from your mapping). For this particular use case is not really needed and your original will work.

Comment: I have tried this but still nothing. Though you are right, this was another problem in my code, but this would have just returned really bad results as lat and lng would have been reversed. I fixed it now, and still same problem persists - no hits when using geo_distance filter. Check my question. I have added more info, expected data and mappings.

Comment: @AndriusBartulis Check my answer again, I've just edited it :)

Comment: Looks like its working! I can now search using geo_distance filter. So how would I incorporate this nested filtered query with a bool - must - fuzzy like this? In other words, I want to get all entities that are within x miles of x geopoint and where the entity name or categories contains term x using fuzziness of 2. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, how would I get the distance between my specified geopoint in my query and the found entity? I have seen people do it with some scripts, but surely there should be an easier way, something like mysql's query AS distance?

Comment: 1.- [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) can contain the query you need under the property `query`

Comment: 2.- Look at [this](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/sorting-by-distance.html) to get some ideas on how to get the distance.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With your answers I got everything to work! And it's tons faster then my previous MySQL solution!